# QWidget not showing after calling show()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, show

In My App, I have a QWidget which is not showing after I call `show()`, even though `isVisible` returns `true`.

This widget is created from an event of the main application window. But when its started on its own, i.e., as the only widget on an app, it shows up normally.

Anyone knows what may cause this behavior?

Other widgets in my app show up normally only this one is giving me troubles. It actually use to work just fine under a previous version of Qt4 (don't remember which).

the code for the widget is [here](http://code.google.com/p/hidx/source/browse/GUI/viz/scatmat.py)

update: windows seems to appear and is immediately destroyed.

Comment: Which object in that script are you referring to? What event creates it? And what do you mean by "show" - show as a child widget, or show as a separate window?

Comment: class Scatmat creates a Qwidget, pw, which is supposed to show up as a separate window. the evente which activates it is "on_actionScatterplot_Matrix_activated" from the MainWindow class of main.py from the same project. If you execute the scatmat module you will see the widget as it is supposed to apper in the application.

Comment: That's a weird design. Why doesn't `Scatmat` derive from `QWidget`?

Comment: @Avaris : the quick answer is that this evolved from a standalone script, and I  saw no need to refactor it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant code is in `hidx/GUI/main.py`:

```
@pyqtSignature("")
def on_actionScatterplot_Matrix_activated(self):
    ...
    spm = scatmat.ScatMat(pars, self.currentdbname)
    print "==>", spm.pw.isVisible()
    spm.pw.hide()
    spm.pw.showMaximized()
    print spm.pw.size()
    print "==>", spm.pw.isVisible()

@pyqtSignature("int")
def on_rowStart_valueChanged(self, p0):
    ...
```

In `on_actionScatterplot_Matrix_activated`, you create an instance of `ScatMat`, but don't keep a reference to it. So the window will be briefly shown, and then immediately garbage-collected once the function completes.

Comment: Thanks Ekhumoro, Now that you mentioned, it's so obvious! (shame on me) What kept me from seeing the obvious was that this used to work a while ago, the only explanation I can find is that Python's garbage collector got more efficient recently. I even tried the faulty code on ubuntu 11.04 (python 2.7.1) and the QWidget did not get garbage collected. I currently use 11.10 (python 2.7.2) and after I followed your suggestion it all started working.