# QWidgets not showing after show() -- c++/Qt5

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface

I am currently working on a Database Management Software with Qt5. I would like to hide some of my widgets linked to the main layout of the program, and then to show them again (using a QComboBox to select whether or not to show). All widget are members of the MainWindow class.
This is how I create the widgets :

```
void MainWindow::mode1Buildup()
{
    extractTables();
    mod1TableDesc = new QLabel("Cette requête a pour but \n de filtrer la table client \n avec ce paramètre :");
    mainLayout->addWidget(mod1TableDesc,3,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    QSqlQuery query;
    if(query.exec("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA='auchan' AND TABLE_NAME='approvisionnement')"))
    {
        while(query.next())
        {
            fieldNames.push_back(q2c(query.value(0).toString()));
        }
        createFieldBox();
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::about(this, "Tables non récupérées", "La récupération des tables a échouée");
    }
    exactBox = new QComboBox;
    exactBox->addItem("Contient");
    exactBox->addItem("Commence par");
    exactBox->addItem("fini par");
    exactBox->addItem("Condition");
    mainLayout->addWidget(exactBox, 5,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    filter1 = new QComboBox;
    filter1->addItem("=");
    filter1->addItem("<=");
    filter1->addItem(">=");
    filter1->addItem("<");
    filter1->addItem(">");
    mainLayout->addWidget(filter1,6,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    value = new QLineEdit();
    mainLayout->addWidget(value,7,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    value->setObjectName("test1");
    borderBox = new QCheckBox("Cochez pour avoir une valeur \n comprise dans un ensemble", this);
    connect(borderBox, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(makeInter()));
    mainLayout->addWidget(borderBox, 8,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    lowvalueDesc = new QLabel("Entrez la valeur minimum");
    mainLayout->addWidget(lowvalueDesc, 9,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    lowvalueDesc->setVisible(false);
    lowvalue = new QLineEdit();
    mainLayout->addWidget(lowvalue, 10,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    lowvalue->setVisible(false);
    highvalueDesc = new QLabel("Entrez la valeur maximum");
    mainLayout->addWidget(highvalueDesc, 11,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    highvalueDesc->setVisible(false);
    highvalue = new QLineEdit();
    mainLayout->addWidget(highvalue, 12,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    highvalue->setVisible(false);
    recherche1 = new QPushButton("recherche");
    connect(recherche1, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(execReq1()));
    mainLayout->addWidget(recherche1,13,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);


}
```

This is how I hide them :

```
void MainWindow::mode1Cleanup()
{
    mod1TableDesc->hide();
    fieldSelect->hide();
    value->hide();
    filter1->hide();
    exactBox->hide();
    borderBox->hide();
    lowvalue->hide();
    highvalue->hide();
    recherche1->hide();
    highvalueDesc->hide();
    lowvalueDesc->hide();
}
```

And this is how I show them :

```
void MainWindow::mode1Rebuild()
{
    mod1TableDesc->show();
    fieldSelect->show();
    value->show();
    filter1->show();
    exactBox->show();
    borderBox->show();
    lowvalue->show();
    lowvalueDesc->show();
    highvalue->show();
    highvalueDesc->show();
    recherche1->show();
}
```

However, I never manage to display them again. They are not removed from the main layout. I am thinking maybe they are caught by the garbage collector, but I'm not sure how to check/fix that.

For wanting the full code :
https://github.com/Sysmetryx/ESME-PROJET-IHM-BDD/tree/V.2Debug

I also tried with ->setVisible(true) and setVisible(false), but being equivalent, it changed nothing.
Also I took a look at this thread :
[QWidget not showing after calling show()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242770/qwidget-not-showing-after-calling-show)
And did not understand the answer, mostly because it's in Python.

Thank you for your time,
best regards,
Nathan

Comment: Your problem is caused by a typo, you have one more comma in the `if` statements: https://github.com/Sysmetryx/ESME-PROJET-IHM-BDD/blob/V.2Debug/mainwindow.cpp#L171: `else if(reqSelect->currentText() == "Insertion de données")**;**`, https://github.com/Sysmetryx/ESME-PROJET-IHM-BDD/blob/V.2Debug/mainwindow.cpp#L380: `if(query.exec(sqlQuery))**;**` and https://github.com/Sysmetryx/ESME-PROJET-IHM-BDD/blob/V.2Debug/mainwindow.cpp#L424: `if(query.exec(queryText))**;**`. Remove those commas and your program will run correctly.

Comment: All these cases return the following warning: **warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]**, therefore I think that this question must be closed because it is a simple typographical error which does not help the SO community at all.

Comment: Thank you for seeing that, it solved the problem right away.
It should indeed be closed. Sorry for bothering you with a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really not see the reason add widgets to layout via code. Place widgets in UI file, setup it's in code and hide on start. That *may* help you make code clear and resolve your issue.

If you not want make widgets in UI file. You should assign "parent" for new widgets. 
For example:

```
value = new QLineEdit();
```

is wrong approach. Please use next template:

```
value = new QLineEdit( this );
```

That may help you too.

Comment: It is advisable to pass a parent to him but it is not obligatory or necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about the parent, I will add them, it will probably be cleaner.
I am required by one of my teachers not to use the UI unfortunately.

Comment: PRO TIP: Make it using designer first, then simply copy the generated code into the project and delete .ui. Then your teacher cannot complain!